# how to check if the user is on a trial period or not using the API 'purchases.subscriptionsv2.get'

Tags: java, server

how to distinguish if the user is on a trial period or not if using the new Android Publisher API 'purchases.subscriptionsv2.get' ([https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/%7Btoken%7D))

There is no field like 'paymentState' which is 2 means free trial in the old API 'purchases.subscriptions.get'.

Thanks.

the version is 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v3-rev20230313-2.0.0'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 11/01/2023**

After conducting in-depth research and testing on this issue, we found the meaning of `OfferId`. Let me explain it with one detailed example.

**The first subscription purchase**

Suppose there is a subscription whose productId is `pid.aaa.bbb` with a 7-day period and a free trial of 3 days. One user purchased this subscription for the first time on 10/01/2023, and the transaction id of this purchase is `GPA.1111`. The value of `OfferId` is **not empty** and is equal to the offer name configured in this subscription. Therefore, the user could be in the `free trial` period until 10/04/2023. After 10/04/2023, the real subscription takes effect, and the user could be in the first period of the subscription until 10/11/2023. The transaction id of this purchase could be `GPA.111..0`, and the value of `OfferId` is **not empty** either.

When this user cancels the subscription on 10/10/2023, the whole subscription purchase period is complete.

**The second subscription purchase**

However, this user repurchased the same subscription several days later on 10/15/2023. The transaction id of this new purchase is `GPA.2222`, and the value of `OfferId` is **empty** since there is **NO** `free trial` period for this new purchase. The expiration time of this purchase is 10/22/2023. After 10/22/2023, the new subscription period takes effect, and the transaction id is `GPA.2222..0`, and the value of `OfferId` is **empty**.

We know that the `free trial` does **NOT** take effect in the second purchase period, so the value of `OfferId` is empty.

**Solution to distinguish the free trial**

Based on the above, both the value of `OfferId` and `transaction id` are used to distinguish the free trial period of a subscription. **Only when the `OfferId` is not empty and there is NO ".." in the `transaction id`, the value of the `free trial` is `true`**.

---

**Some Basic concepts**

Starting in May 2022, a subscription’s benefits (in other words, “what” the subscription provides) are defined separately from its base plans and offers (“how” the subscription is sold). This new model makes it easier to sell your subscriptions in various ways

[image]

The resulting subscriptions, base plans, and offers have the same functionality as before. For instance, you can change the length of a free trial, update a subscription’s description, or change your grace period length.

We know the `Offer` phase of the new subscription is equal to the `free trial` phase of the old subscription.

---

For the `subscriptionV2`, the `OfferDetails`(https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2#OfferDetails) could Only present for discounted offers, aka `free trial` in here.

In my case, the subscription was upgraded to the following state in the Googleplay console

[image]

---

Refs

- [May 2022 subscription changes guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/compatibility)
- [Upcoming changes to InAppProducts API and subscription catalog management](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/06/changes-to-google-play-developer-api-june-2023.html)
- [Recent changes to subscriptions in Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12124625?sjid=17486101450934548233-NA)